# Homology group of an infinite wedge product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm struggling with the following algebraic topology problem:

I'm given a collection of (topological) spaces $(X_i)_i$, ($i\in I$ whatever) and for each space a point $x_i\in X_i$. Then $\bigvee_i X_i$ is defined by gluing all the spaces together by the points $x_i$.

I should then be able to show that $\oplus_i (\iota_i)_* : \oplus_i H_q(X_i)\to H_q(\bigvee_i X_i)$ is an isomorphism $\forall q>0$, under the hypotheses of $(x_i)_i$ being a closed set in the disjoint union topology and each of the $x_i$ having a nbhd in $X_i$ which deformation retracts on themselves.
(Here $\iota_{i*} $ denotes the homomorphism induced by the usual inclusion from $X_i$ to $\bigvee_i X_i$.)

My problem: I cannot even conceive how to use my hypotheses. It is immediate to show $\oplus_i (\iota_i)_*$ to be an homomorphism, but then I get stuck. How do I translate my topological hypotheses in an useful algebraic statement? I cannot even see the intuitive reasons for which such hypotheses should be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypothesis implies that $A=\{x_i:i\in I\}$ has a neighborhood in $\bigsqcup_i X_i$, which deformation retract onto $A$. Then using the excision theorem we have the isomorphism,
$$H_n(\bigsqcup X_i, A)\to H_n(\bigsqcup_i X_i/A,A/A)=H_n(\bigvee_i X_i, x),$$
where $x$ is the wedge point.

Now, the inclusion maps $\tau_i:(X_i,x_i)\to(\bigsqcup_iX_i,A)$ induces another isomorphism, $$\oplus_i(\tau_i)_* : \bigoplus_iH_n(X_i,x_i)\cong H_n(\bigsqcup_iX_i,A)$$

Also, $H_n(\bigvee_iX_i,x)\cong\tilde H_n(\bigvee_iX_i)=H_n(\bigvee_i X_i)$ and $H_n(X_i,x_i)\cong H_n(X_i)$, for $n\geq 1$.

So combining all these,
$$H_n(\bigvee_i X_i)\cong \bigoplus_i H_n(X_i),n\ge1$$